# debug osx kernel error: KDP_REATTACH failed

Tags: macos, debugging, kernel, lldb

I run lldb command "kdp-remote 172.16.4.150" on the host terminal,and it report an  error "error: KDP_REATTACH failed", Who can help me？
the virtual machine show message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ym43.png)